# How to access typeconverted elements declared in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I declared

```
<sys:DateTime> 2009/09/01 3:33:33 
</sys:DateTime>  in xaml via <ListBox xmlns:sys="clr-namespace=System;assembly:mscorlib" >
```

I'm doing this

```
DateTime newDate = ((DateTime)(MyListBox.Items.GetItemAt(1)));
newDate = DateTime.Now;
```

but  `sys:DateTime`'s value is not changing??

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is a value type. It will not exhibit reference semantics like you wish. You'll have to assign back to the original in order to update it.